# MVC Routing - Generate the Route URL With Good Coding Standards

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm learning how to do routing in MVC. It seems to me that the routing API only solves half the problem. I can easily see how to map incoming URLs to controller actions and params. However, it is not obvious to me how to generate these routed URLs in the source code of my pages.

For example, in one of my views, I use this code to get the route URL:

```
<a class="listingResult" href="@Url.RouteUrl("ListingSEO", new { id = Model.Listing.ID, seoName = ListingController.SeoName(Model.Listing.Title) })">
```

This seems like poor coding practice to me for several reasons:

1. If the route changes in the future, I may have many places in my View code that will need updating.
2. The View now requires knowledge of the ListingController (maybe this is not a big deal?)
3. I've lost strong typing on my input params, and if I misspell the param names, my code is broken, but this doesn't generate compile warnings.

How do I observe good coding standards when I am generating route URLs? The alternative seems to be putting static functions in the controller to generate routes, which would at least address concerns #1 and #3. If I worked with you and you saw the code above, how unhappy would you be?

Comment: What does `ListingController.SeoName(Model.Listing.Title)` actually do? Are you trying to append a friendly query string (i.e. a 'slug') as in the address bar above - in which case this should be done using an `FilterAttribute`

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing.

Comment: I found this article on the technique you suggest (https://danielweberonline.wordpress.com/category/technical/asp-net-mvc/), but it doesn't suggest a more elegant way to generate the URLs in the emitted HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendations:

1. **Generate URLs in the ViewModel, not the View**: This will keep your views cleaner and logic free. You can pass the UrlHelper instance from the controller to the ViewModel, which will also help for my next point...
2. **Use a strongly-typed URL generation technique**: Such as [delegate-based](http://maxtoroq.github.io/2013/04/delegate-based-strongly-typed-url.html), [expression-based](http://eduncan911.com/blog/archives/type-safety-with-asp-net-mvc-futures.html) or [code generation](https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC).

Answer (score 1):

1. One of the purposes of using named routes is to abstract the controller/action. Your named routes shouldn't really change. At the most, you'd just change the controller/action they hit, but that happens seamlessly behind the scenes *because you're using named routes*.
2. Your view requires knowledge of the controller because you've added a dependency on it. This is bad for a number of reasons. There's many different ways you could handle this that wouldn't require a dependency on the controller, depending on what it is you're actually doing here, but at the very least, you should simply use a utility class, so at least it wouldn't be controller-specific.
3. The route params are intentionally not strongly-typed, because routes are flexible by design. You can pass anything you want to the action, with or without a parameter to catch it (you can use something like `Request` to get at it without a param).